# Is there a better way to access my public api?

Tags: python, flask

I am new to Flask.

I have a public api, call it api.example.com.

```
@app.route('/api')
def api():
  name = request.args.get('name')
  ...
  return jsonify({'address':'100 Main'})
```

I am building an app on top of my public api (call it www.coolapp.com), so in another app I have:

```
@app.route('/make_request')
def index():
  params = {'name':'Fred'}
  r = requests.get('http://api.example.com', params=params)
  return render_template('really_cool.jinja2',address=r.text)
```

Both api.example.com and www.coolapp.com are hosted on the same server. It seems inefficient the way I have it (hitting the http server when I could access the api directly). Is there a more efficient way for coolapp to access the api and still be able to pass in the params that api needs?

Comment: Note that, if this is a REST API (as it looks like), using `requests.get` **is** using the (REST) API directly. Did you mean to ask how to access the python functions of another flask app?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean. So, rather than hit the public url I'd hit the function directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, with an API powered system, it's best to hit the API because:

- It's user testing the API (even though you're the user, it's what others still access);
- You can then scale easily - put a pool of API boxes behind a load balancer if you get big.

However, if you're developing on the same box you could make a virtual server that listens on `localhost` on a random port (`1982`) and then forwards all traffic to your `api` code.

To make this easier I'd abstract the `API_URL` into a setting in your `settings.py` (or whatever you are loading in to Flask) and use:

```
r = requests.get(app.config['API_URL'], params=params)
```

This will allow you to make a single change if you find using this `localhost` method isn't for you or you have to move off one box.

## Edit

Looking at your comments you are hoping to hit the Python function directly. I don't recommend doing this (for the reasons above - using the API itself is better). I can also see an issue if you did want to do this.

- First of all we have to make sure the `api` package is in your `PYTHONPATH`. Easy to do, especially if you're using virtualenvs.
- We `from api import views` and replace our code to have `r = views.api()` so that it calls our `api()` function.
- Our `api()` function will fail for a couple of reasons:

  1. It uses the `flask.request` to extract the `GET` `arg` 'name'. Because we haven't made a request with the flask WSGI we will not have a `request` to use.
  2. Even if we did manage to pass the request from the front end through to the API the second problem we have is using the `jsonify({'address':'100 Main'})`. This returns a `Response` object with an application type set for JSON (not just the `JSON` itself). 
     You would have to completely rewrite your function to take into account the `Response` object and handle it correctly. A real pain if you do decide to go back to an API system again...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you structure your code, your database access, and your functions, you can simply turn the other app into package, import the relevant modules and call the functions directly.

You can find more information on modules and packages [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).

Please note that, as Ewan mentioned, there's some advantages to using the API. I would advise you to use `requests` until you actually *need* faster requests (this is probably *premature optimization*).

Another idea that might be worth considering, depending on your particular code, is creating a library that is used by both applications.